# Set SQL Server Syntax

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to set SQL Server 2008 R2 to just accept the ANSI SQL-92 syntax ?

So, when I do query using ANSI SQL-89 syntax, It will show some error.

If yes, how to do that ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can monitor for the use of deprecated features by using the SQL Server Deprecated Features Object performance counter and trace events.  You won't get realtime warnings, but you don't want that anyway - it would break your apps.  Instead, you just want to monitor afterwards to see what code you need to go fix.

Answer (score -1):

Dont think so

Run `sp_configure` and see if you get such an option.. I can't see any on my box.

Comment: Really hate down vote without comment.. If you really think it was incorrect give reason.